# Why is Lord Robert Arryn named Robert?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Was Robert Arryn named Robert to honour King Robert? Whose choice was it?

Comment: Presumably his father and mother, Jon Arryn and Lysa Tully? Why would someone else do it? Since Robert was Jon's ward and they were close, presumably it is an homage to Robert.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Robert Arryn](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Robert_Arryn#cite_note-Ragot4.7B.7B.7B3.7D.7D.7D-0) was named after King **Robert** Baratheon, in honour of his father's affiliation with the monarch. In the book "[A Game of Thrones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Game_of_Thrones)", Robert Baratheon says;

> "**The boy is my namesake**, did you know that? Robert Arryn. I am sworn
>   to protect him. How can I do that if his mother steals him away?"

---

In answer to the second part of your question, there seems to be no canon description of *who* named him but there's also no reason to assume that it wasn't his parents; Jon Arryn and Lysa Tully.

Comment: Your quote really only says that Robert said they had the same name. Not sure where the "sworn to protect" comes from, but it feels pretty certain that it has nothing to do with his name.

Comment: @TLP - In american usage, namesake almost always means "named after" rather than the English usage which generally means "named the same as". Also, the rest of the quote makes no sense if he just means "*we share a similar name*" since obviously Ned knows that already...

Comment: It is clear that Jon named his son after Robert, since as we can see, they both have the same name, and it would be silly to assume otherwise, considering how close they were. Likewise, Ned obviously named his son after Jon. And possibly Robb/Robert. (And curiously we learn that there is a Edric "Ned" Dayne.) That does not mean that either person is sworn to protect their namesakes. I don't know why Robert had sworn to protect Jon's son, but if anything, it was not because they had the same name.

Comment: @tlp - That's a separate question. Ivo's question is "who is he named after"...

Comment: Well, you were the one that said that the rest of the quote proved the naming part. :P I am just saying that the quote is irrelevant. If you wanted proof that Robert was named after Robert, you could say things like: Robert and Jon were very close, Robert was Jon's ward, Jon went to war for Robert's sake, so it is fairly clear that it is not just a coincidence they have the same name.

Comment: You misunderstand me.  The second part of the quote ("did you know that?") proves that he was named after him whereas your comment is basically a fan theory with no foundation

Comment: Oh, I see, my pardons. I still think that you could make a better case with the evidence that Jon and Robert were close friends. While it is possible that your quote says "The boy was named after me, did you know?", it is equally possible that it says "The boy has the same name as me, did you know?" Robert and Ned have not met in a great long while since the rebellion, so it is not at all certain Robert would know that Ned knew Jon's son's name. Also, since GRRM has based so much of his books on England, even language, american usage of words is not a solid argument.

Comment: Not that it matters all that much either way. I just think there are better ways to prove that this naming was intentional.

Comment: sound reasoning between the answer and the comments. I see where TLP is coming from, but would add that, although news may travel slowly, it is more than likely that Ned would have been told the name of Jon Arryn's son prior to the conversation with Robert quoted above - hence the interpretation of "did you know [he was named after me]?" seems valid.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister Except that if Robert knew that Ned knew that Jon named his son after Robert, that would mean that he (Robert) was stating something obvious. That would be like Ned saying to Robert: `I named my boy Jon. I named him after Jon Arryn, did you know? Jon Snow! Because.. Jon - Jon, same name. And also, my son Brandon, I named him after my brother Brandon. Bet you didn't know that. Also, here's something that will surprise you: You know my son Robb?` etc. Although I am guessing that GRRM did not put as much thought into writing the statement as we did in reading it.

Comment: @TLP agreed it's a clunky piece of exposition. But I guess the point is that while it may be obvious they have the same name, it may not be obvious that the name was chosen to honour King Robert. If this is not the correct interpretation, how then would you explain Ned not knowing (as of Chapter 4) the name of the 6 year-old son of the man who fostered him as a boy? And let's assume his closeness to Jon Arryn is irrelevant - it still doesn't stack up. The event of the birth of an heir to the Vale would be big news, the kind of news that ought to reach all corners of the Seven Kingdoms.

Comment: 6 years is more than enough time for that news to have reached Winterfell. Admittedly this may be a case of using in-universe logic to explain something that could be an (out-of-universe) error on GRRM's part, but it's the only way I can make it work in my head.

Comment: I don't see it as an issue. It's pretty clear that he's asking if ned knows that the boy was named for him.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister That's all well and good if you are an omniscient observer, but GRRM notoriously uses subjective perspectives, so it would have to depend on what Robert knew that Ned knew. It doesn't matter what we know, what matters is what Robert knows, or doesn't know. The only real reason Robert would have of *knowing* Ned knew the name is if they talked about it. Anyway, I think we are grossly overestimating GRRM's attention to detail here. I reiterate my opinion that there are better ways to prove this than this rather random quote.

Comment: @Richard Well, my position is this: If you were supposed to "prove" the theory of relativity, would it be a better idea to quote a physics textbook, or to show a quote of Einstein saying "Well, everything is relative." I could give you ten bits of information right now that would be better in showing why Jon Arryn picked this name for his son: 1) Robert was a ward at Jon's when he was young, and they became close, 2) so close that Jon defied the king and went to war for his sake, 3) he even married a Tully to secure allies for Robert, 4) he brokered Robert's marriage to Cersei...

Comment: ...securing the Lannister alliance, 5) he became Robert's Hand, 6) eh.. ok, too much work, but you get the idea. :)

Comment: @TLP It's clear that the boy was named after Robert *because he told us so*. It's not at all clear that Jon Snow was named after Jon Arryn, or that he is even Ned's son.